# One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

Tags: c#, .net, complex-numbers

got an error One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

can not see where is wrong about the operator overloadin

error at public static Complex operator **+**(Complex c1, Complex c2)

```
namespace testComplex
{
    class Program
    {

        public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2)
        {
            return new Complex(c1.Real + c2.Real, c1.Imaginary + c2.Imaginary);
        }

        public static Complex operator /(Complex c1, Complex c2)
        {
            return new Complex(c1.Real / c2.Real, c1.Imaginary / c2.Imaginary);
        }

        public static Complex operator *(Complex c1, Complex c2)
        {
            return new Complex(c1.Real * c2.Real, c1.Imaginary * c2.Imaginary + c1.Real * c2.Imaginary + c2.Real * c1.Imaginary);
        }
        public static Complex operator -(Complex c1, Complex c2)
        {
            return new Complex(c1.Real - c2.Real, c1.Imaginary - c2.Imaginary);
        }

        //public static Complex Sqrt -(Complex c1, Complex c2)
        //{
            //return new Complex(c1.Real - c2.Real, c1.Imaginary - c2.Imaginary);
        //}
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Complex a = new Complex(0.5,0);
            Complex b = new Complex(0.6,0);

            //Complex aa = Math.Exp(-(1 / 4) * a * (b / a + Math.Sqrt(-7 * Math.Pow(b, 2) / Math.Pow(a, 2))) / b + (1 / 4) * b * (a / b + Math.Sqrt(-7 * Math.Pow(a, 2) / Math.Pow(b, 2))) / a);
            //Jesus[i] = aa.Real;

            Complex aa = Complex.Exp(-(1 / 4) * a * (b / a + Complex.Sqrt(-7 * Complex.Pow(b, 2) / Complex.Pow(a, 2))) / b + (1 / 4) * b * (a / b + Complex.Sqrt(-7 * Complex.Pow(a, 2) / Complex.Pow(b, 2))) / a);
            Console.WriteLine(aa.Real);
            Console.WriteLine(aa.Imaginary);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? What do you mean by nothing to output?

Comment: it output NaN of the whole equation

Comment: What is it you are trying to do ? Where is it you want to "output" ? What is **Jesus** ?

Comment: ...and why is he real?

Comment: *What is Jesus ?* Simon, S.O. is only for ["..practical, answerable questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ;-)

Comment: Add a breakpoint on your statement and do a quick debug on each subexpression to find where you get the NaN from.

Comment: You might also want to review the docs, which mention [several conditions which cause an `NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Leigh for the love of the invisible pink unicorn I wanted to know about the variable ! Not start a theological discussion ! I swear ! Don't downvote me !

Comment: Ah crud, sorry @Leigh, missed your comment on the doc

Comment: Jesus is just a variable name, this equation pass symmetric, transitive and identity test, but it output complex number

Comment: You define your operators in class Program, they should be in class Complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.aspx) is the doc on complex structure in C#, there is a part explaining why you might be getting a **NaN**

You are doing divisions so you might be dividing by zero, you will need to debug your equation further, I would recommend checking it outside of C# with the values that give you a **NaN**

Comment: *missed your comment on the doc* Ahh.. and I did not see this answer before my last comment. It all makes sense now ;-)